# Recognition of web page

Tags: email

We have recently launched our web page but cannot find it on Google.if we type in our name nothing comes through but if we include.com then the site comes up on google.
We used many key words thinking this would help customers locate our site, but type these key words in and still we are not listed.
Can you advise if we are doing something wrong
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A new website will take time to rank in Google (it can be months before you start to show up for a specific term, depending on the level of competition). After you submit your site to Google, there will be a period of time where they will attempt to "figure you out" and index your content. SEO (and Google in general) is a waiting game.